# put external javascript file inside one main file

Tags: jquery, css

I have an external javascript file which is opened when i click a link.
i want to put that coding in same file. (e.g just like we can put css inside style tag )

```
popwindow = window.open(src, name, 'height=500, width=500');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you searching for something like that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Copy your javascript code here
</script>
```

Comment: Developers often use this technique for putting environment variables in their main javascript files. Just make sure you embed this inline `<script>` tag _before_ your other javascript files, if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the `<script>` tag. This tag is what you use for writing Javascript in an HTML document and connecting an external JS file. For an example:

```html
<script>
  popwindow = window.open(src, name, 'height=500, width=500');  
</script>
```

This would run the code you are looking for without making an external file (running it should not show any results). If you want to connect an external file (say your .js file is called `myScript`), write this:

```
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
```

That would connect an external file. Also note that you don't need the `type="text/javascript"` because Javascript has been standardized as the default scripting language for HTML.

You can also use this method to add javascript frameworks and plugins to your website. Lets say you want to throw in jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps!